# Controller is looking for HTML format instead of JS format (though we set :remote => true)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I have the following link_to:

```
<%= link_to 'user_' + user.id.to_s, {:controller => 'admin', :action => 'view_user', :id => user.id}, :remote => true %>
```

However, when I click that link, I get the following error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate at /admin/view_user
Missing template admin/view_user, application/view_user with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml, :rabl]}.
Searched in: /Users/me/Documents/production/my_app/app/views
```

It should be looking for view_user.js.erb. That file definitely exists.

This issue seems to have come up after I changed how I deal with jquery & jquery-ui. I am now using the jquery-ui-rails gem. I removed the lines requiring jquery-ui and jquery_ujs from my application.js file. I don't know of anyway to add jquery_ujs (maybe it is packaged with rails?)

Any clue what might be going on? What's puzzling is, I figured explicitly saying :remote => true would result in the JS file being rendered.

here's what view_user looks like:

```
def view_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  user_show_helper
end
```

user_show_helper is a huge method that basically sets a bunch of instance variables necessary to show the snippet of a user profile (i.e. there is no render method called in user_show_helper).

Here's what view_user.js.erb looks like:

```
$("#user_under_review").html("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'admin/view_user' ) %>");
```

And here's what the partial _view_user.html.erb looks like:

```
<%= render 'users/user_brief' %>
<div class="table_td_middle" id="<%= 'user_number_' + @user.id.to_s %>">
  <%= link_to 'Approve user?', approve_user_as_admin_path(@user.id), :remote => true, :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to approve this user?' %>
</div>
```

Comment: This is likely an issue with your controller. Can you please post the controller action you're trying to render from?

Comment: You're incorrectly invoking the use of helpers. Helpers are designed for use in views solely. There's no way you'll get one to work by default in a controller.

Comment: what do you mean exactly? I could basically be doing the exact same stuff that I'm doing in the helper method within the controller itself ... but the helper is from a different controller (user controller). basically, in order to render a user, I user the user_show_helper in a bunch of places. all it does is DB queries and set instance vars to results of these queries.

Comment: Rails helpers are actually _view_ helpers, and are not designated to work within controllers out of the box. If you need to use a helper in a controller (which as you said, is redundant, since you can do all the helper code in the controller anyways), you'll need to import it into your controller class: `include UserShowHelper`

Comment: oh yeah, I have that all setup! no issue there actually. the issue is just that the controller is trying to serve up a .html format, though I set :remote => true and the view_user method is now set to respond with .js format ONLY. still I get served a (blank) HTML page and the server logs indicate "processing ___ as HTML". WHY, I don't know :(

Comment: Understood. See my updated answer for a potential resolution to this issue.

Comment: thanks for your help zeantsoi -- looks like manually including the jquery_ujs file and the requiring it in my application.js file fixed my issues. jquery_ujs helps with a bunch of auxiliary stuff that I needed it looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had removed the jquery-rails gem from my Gemfile and thus had to manually add the jquery_ujs.js file into my assets folder.

I re-added the jquery-rails gem and now we're all good to go!

Great success!!

Answer (score 1):

Your controller doesn't look like it's configured to render out Javascript. The second line of the `ActionView::MissingTemplate` error indicates that the action is only configured to render out HTML: `:formats=>[:html]`.

Have you specified the formats that can be rendered from the controller action?

```
# app/controllers/admin_controller.rb
def view_user
    # Business logic
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
    end
end
```

EDIT:

[The latter answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295300/rails-3-1-link-to-remote-true-renders-html-instead-of-js-the-same-code-works) suggests that `rake assets:precompile` can conditionally resolve issues relating to a `:remote => true` link rendering out HTML, rather than Javascript.

Comment: Hi tried this, but no difference sadly. I've edited my question with  the contest of the controller method.